# What is the timeline to fix the known bug with list and library extension support in the classic experience?

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I  have a working SharePoint Framework extension but I need it to work across 200 classic sites that use the modern library experience.  However, according to the [overview for extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions):

> There is a known bug with list and library extension support in the classic experiences. These only work currently in context of modern team sites, also known as group associated team sites. Work is being done to address this issue.

My question therefore is, given the date on that page is 14 March 2018, is there a timeline for when we think this is likely to be fixed?

Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

No one can give the answer expect the product owner. Sometime it looks like a small bug but on backend it required the structure change or etc, which required a lot efforts.

I would contact the MSFT support to ask about the bug update. OR you can contact one of the contributor of that article which will give you more inside information: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions.md